# Altering precision in HIVE

Tags: hive, precision, hiveql, double-precision

I want to set the precision of a column in my hive table to have a precision of 11 (11 places after the decimal). So say I have the double var:

```
var = 215.6666666666667
```

I want to get this down to two less precision:

```
var = 215.66666666667
```

Is there a way to do this in HIVE? I am using version 0.12.

Comment: `round(DOUBLE x, INT y)` returns `x` rounded to `y` decimal places.  Straight from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DECIMAL` datatype in Hive which allows you to specify scale and precision of the decimal datatype when creating the table.The `DECIMAL` type in Hive is as same as Big Decimal format of Java. It is used for representing immutable arbitrary precision. The syntax and example is as follows:

```
DECIMAL(precision, scale)
decimal(10,0)
```

But Hive 0.12 does not support precision and scale for decimal. [HIVE-3976](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3976) added support for decimal scale and precision, and is available in Hive 0.13.